# Python 3.0 - Assign range loop output to variable

Tags: python, loops

```
#Imports
import string
import random
import time


digits = string.digits
letters = string.ascii_letters
punctuation =("!\"\<>@#£$%^&*")
PasswordCode = letters+punctuation+digits

PassLenInput = input("How long should the password be?")
PassLenInput = int(PassLenInput)
for i in range(PassLenInput):
    print(random.choice(PasswordCode),end="")
```

My output looks as follows

```
How long should the password be?4
GtRA
```

I would like to save this output to a variable called pass, and then save that variable to a text file

Thanks

Comment: FYI, you should not use `pass` as a variable name as it shadows pythons [`pass`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#pass) statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I optimized the imports and wrote the password to a file:

```
from string import digits
from string import ascii_letters as letters
import random

punctuation =("!\"\<>@#£$%^&*")
PasswordCode = letters+punctuation+digits

PassLenInput = int(input("How long should the password be?"))

password = ''

for i in range(PassLenInput):
    password += random.choice(PasswordCode)

with open('password_file.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(password)
```

Comment: You could tidy up the code a little more by casting `PassLenInput` to an int on the same line as the input e.g. `PassLenInput = int(input())` :)

Comment: @DavidG: You are right. I have incorporated the hint into my answer.

Answer (score 1):

check out this answer

```
#Imports
import string
import random
import time


digits = string.digits
letters = string.ascii_letters
punctuation =("!\"\<>@#£$%^&*")
PasswordCode = letters+punctuation+digits

PassLenInput = input("How long should the password be?")
PassLenInput = int(PassLenInput)
password = ""
for i in range(PassLenInput):
    password += random.choice(PasswordCode)
    print(password)

#Save Password
with open("password.txt", "w") as save_password:
    save_password.write(password)
```

Comment: you shouldn't use pass as a variable.

Comment: `pass` is a special keyword in python, so changed it. Thought it does'nt matter in this case.

Comment: This code has 2 problems, the output is all on different lines, and the text file only has the last letter generated